# Regex containg a variable

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

Regex and variables seem to be a current issue here, yet I didn't find an answer to my problem.

It is quite simple, i am using a noSQL database system for javascript called nedb. pretty neat by the way. [GitHub link](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/wiki/Finding-documents)

Here is the part that matters for us :

```
// Finding all planets whose name contain the substring 'ar' using a regular expression
db.find({ planet: /ar/ }, function (err, docs) {
  // docs contains Mars and Earth
});
```

as you see, the expression /ar/ means "containing the substring ar", which is classic regex. 
What I want is replacing ar by a variable (the result of a user search).

```
Like this : 
var search = ‘ar'; //taken from an HTML form
db.find ({planet : ‘/‘ + search + ‘/‘}, fonction (err,docs) {
}
```

This unfortunately does not work. Neither does :

```
  var search = ‘/ar/'; 
    db.find ({planet : search}, fonction (err,docs) {
    }
```

Do you have any ideas ? Might seem prettu obvious to you, but i am losing my mind on this issue aha !
thank you guys

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: You have strange quotes. `‘` should be `'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the RegExp constructor :

```
db.find({ planet: new RegExp(yourString) }, function (err, docs) {
```

If your string can be anything, you'd better escape it. See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) then.

Comment: hi, seems weirt but this actually works...

var search = "var";
db.translation.find({translate : new RegExp(search)},function(err,docs){}


yeah, without any / around... it works and thank you a lot but still.. wtf

Comment: Why does it seem weird ?

Comment: because the absence of / ... i'm confused but well, it works doesn't it

Comment: `/` delimits a regular expression literal, that is a regular expression that you don't have to build from a string using the RegExp contructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor, but this alone is not enough (`.` would be "any character", `?` would mean the previous character is optional and `/` would break your regex, as well as all the other regular regex keywords and characters).

You can avoid this by using a regex escaping function (such as[`preg_quote` from PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote/)) which will escape them:

```
db.find({ planet: new RegExp(preg_quote(searchString, '/')) }, function (err, docs) {
```

Comment: hi, thank for your help, preg_quote is not recognized though..

Comment: @user3401138: follow the link in the answer...